# TypeScript: Conditional Intersection via Discriminated Union

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I'm try to efficiently add properties to an object type based on one of the existing property values. For example, there is a default type `BaseField` shared between many types of fields. The type of the field comes from an enum. For example:

```
enum FieldType {
  Currency = 'currency',
  Text = 'text',
}

type BaseField<T extends FieldType = FieldType> = {
  id: string;
  type: T;
}
```

Some fields have additional properties depending on their type. For example, a field with type `Currency` also has a `defaultCurrency` property. I originally tried to use a map and a discriminated union to achieve this, something like:

```
type CurrencyField = {
  defaultCurrency: string;
}

type FieldMap = {
  [FieldType.Currency]: CurrencyField,
  [FieldType.Text]: never,
}

type Field<T extends FieldType = FieldType> = T extends T 
  ? BaseField<T> & FieldMap[T] 
  : never;
```

This *half* works. If I create a field as such:

```
const field: Field = {
  id: 'field1',
  type: FieldType.Currency,
}
```

I correctly get a type error `Property 'defaultCurrency' is missing in type`. And, if I add it in, the type is valid. However, the issue arises when I use one of the types where the `FieldMap` has the value of `never`. If I try to make a text field:

```
const field: Field = {
  id: 'field2',
  type: FieldType.Text,
}
```

I see the error `Type 'FieldType.Text' is not assignable to type 'FieldType.Currency'.`. I have tried a few ways to get around this:

1. Instead of `never` use `BaseField` as the type in the map
2. Remove the params from `BaseField` type
3. Modify the union to `BaseField<T> & T extends T ? FieldMap[T] : never;`

However, I am unable to resolve this. I can get it to work by manually creating the fields and joining them together:

```
type CurrencyField = {
  id: string;
  defaultCurrency: string;
  type: FieldType.Currency;
}

type TextField = {
  id: string;
  type: FieldType.Text;
}

type Field = CurrencyField | TextField;
```

However, I'd like to keep this as scalable as possible and would rather not have to create new types every time a new field was added. Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why are you using `never`?  You probably want `{}` or `unknown` instead, if the intent is for it to be absorbed into an intersection.

Comment: This was indeed the issue. Thank you! My thought was that `never `is the "empty set" so the union of the `BaseField<T> | never` would yield `BaseField<T>`. I'll need to wrap my head around this but it definitely helps. Thank you again.

Comment: Right, but you are using an *intersection*, not a *union*.  Shall I write up an answer, then?  (Or is there some way to ping @lawrence-witt, who appears to have started writing up an answer suggesting this very thing?).

Comment: I would be very grateful for your answer! I see now in my original discussion I was using the intersection. That makes total sense now.